# Why is fuzzy.ratio not 100 for exact same strings?

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have two data frames df1 and df2. Both the data frames have a column with movie_names. I am trying to match movie_name1 in df1 with movie_name2 in df2. movie_name1 has values like The Dark Knight RisesÂ , Spider-Man 3Â. movie_name2 has values like The Dark Knight Rises , Spider-Man 3.

We see that there is an extra letter at the end in all the movies in movie_name1. So before matching, I am removing hat extra letter, stripping off the space and then calculating the fuzz.ratio.

This is how I am performing the operation -

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


df1['movie_name1'] = df1['movie_name1'].str.replace( 'Â',"")
df1['movie_name1'] = df1['movie_name1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip()) 
df1['movie_name1_first_letter'] = df1['movie_name1'].astype(str).str.slice(0,1)
df2['movie_name2_first_letter'] = df2['movie_name2'].astype(str).str.slice(0,1)
df_result = pd.merge(df1,mdf2, left_on='movie_name1_first_letter',right_on=
'movie_name2_first_letter')
df_result['Fuzz'] = df_result.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['movie_name1'], 
x['movie_name2']) , axis=1)
```

Sample data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'movie_name1': ['127 hoursÂ','The Dark Knight RisesÂ',
'SpiderManÂ']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'movie_name2': ['The Dark Knight Rises','SpiderMan','127 hours'
]})
```

Sample Result:

```
movie_name1   movie_name2    Fuzz
127 hours     127 hours      90
```

Even when I am performing above operations before calculating the fuzz.ratio, still the fuzz.ratio value for exact same strings is not 100.

My analysis show that there is always a difference of length 2 between the two movie names. For example: the length of '127 hours' in movie_name1 is 11, whereas the length of same movie in movie_name2 is 9. This is happening for all the movies.

Why is it so? Is it because of that letter 'Â'? What can I do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal fully working example of your data and the problem?

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: It's better, but can you also include a sample dataframe in the question, which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Updated the question again!

Comment: Nice! I've copied your data and the code, and the output is `Fuzz=100` for each row. Can you double check that on your machine?

Comment: for me it is not. Because the length of both same strings differ in my case. differ by a length of 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127232/discussion-between-dennis-golomazov-and-dreamer).

Comment: Maybe one of your strings is `unicode` format while the other is `str`.